# How to configure storage for MsSql Export Purpose in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I want to Export `Mssql` file from azure to local system [according to this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export)
But when I go to Export and click on the storage configuration:
[image]

and then it opens configuration form but nothing happen there  and storage option is also closed 

[image]

Any solution for it ?

Comment: try creating a storage account first in the same resource group.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use SqlPackage to export an Azure SQL Database to a local folder in your computer as a bacpac.

```
SqlPackage /Action:Export /SourceServerName:SampleSQLServer.sample.net,1433 /SourceDatabaseName:SampleDatabase /TargetFile:"F:\Temp\SampleDatabase.bacpac"
```

Comment: for this I have to install SQL or just run this command in CMD it will work ? I have just used SQL of Visual Studio not separately installed ?

Comment: The following URL shows you how to obtain it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315074/unable-to-publish-dacpac-to-azure-sql-database-using-sqlpackage-exe/50321062#50321062

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a UI bug in the Azure Portal.

Please create an Storage Account **prior** to exporting the Azure SQL Database and it will be available as follows:

[image]

Comment: It May Works but I did checked it yet .